Install npm Azure Artifacts package from one organization in the pipeline of another organization without PAT
I have created an npm package in Azure Artifacts in Organization1 and want to be able for the pipelines to install it when running in Organization2. Both organizations are in the same tenant.
I have managed to achieve this with a service connection using a PAT. However, this requires a refresh of the PAT every few months and it is connected to a specific person. We do not want this dependency.
Is there another way?


However, this requires a refresh of the PAT every few months and it is connected to a specific person. We do not want this dependency. Is there another way?

As both organizations are in the same tenant, you can setup upstream source on organization2 feed to install the package from organization1.
You can follow the doc Add a feed in a different organization as an upstream source to setup upstream source on organization2 feed.

My NPM upstream resource for your reference:

To install pacakge1 from organization1, i used below task on organziation2 pipeline:

Package installed successfully, and the package will be download to the organziation2 feed. You can check the doc the doc for the upstream behavior.

PS: when you configure upstream source on organization2 feed and save, but encounter permission error like below:

please make sure the source feed on organziation1 was created with Microsoft Entra visibility.


Thanks! It worked. Its important to note that the registryName in the NPM task is from the second organization where we are running the pipelines and not the original npm registry. This was the only thing I was doing wrong when using the Upstreams :D

Glad to know it helps! Happy day!
